# Cannot publish Bot to Azure using npm in VS Code

Tags: azure, npm, azure-bot-service

I'm trying to publish my chatbot application to Azure as instructed in the Azure Portal build menu:
[Screenshot of instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiyXN.png)

I successfully download the code zip file, and it runs fine in VSCode and the Bot Emulator. However, when I do `npm run azure-publish` , I get the error `npm ERR! missing script: azure-publish`. I have not changed any of the build files or the node modules. This exact project runs without an issue in the Azure Online App Editor.

I don't understand where I'm going wrong. Where can I find the script for `azure-publish`? Is it even possible to publish using npm on VS Code? I've seen examples of publishing using Visual Studio, but haven't come across one with VS Code. [Screenshot of directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsPqT.png)

Any help or insight is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you [installed these packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-build-download-source-code?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#publish-node-bot-source-code-to-azure)?

Comment: @stuartd I did, however I had not added the script to my package.json, so thank you for directing me to this link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved!

For anyone who might have the same problem, I had missed adding `"scripts": {"azure-publish": "node publish.js"}` to my `package.json`. Online Code Editor doesn't do it for you, so it has to be manually done if downloading code zip file.